# Too many open files error in Visual Studio Node.js under parallels after upgrade to MacOS Catalina 10.15.7

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2017, macos-catalina, parallels

I just upgraded my Mac to 10.15.7 today.  I run Parallels Desktop on the Mac so I can run my Node.js Visual Studio projects.  Upon doing this upgrade I can no longer get my project to run.  Unfortunately I made a few changes to the code before trying to run but I do not think that is the source of the issue or the log files would be telling me something else.  When I run I get hundred/thousands of lines with the "too many open files" error.  Below is a sample of one of those lines:

SourceMaps: could not preload for generated script: c:\Users\chris\github\CollegeTennisRanks\CollegeTennisRanks\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\string\bold.js. Error: Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'c:\Users\chris\github\CollegeTennisRanks\CollegeTennisRanks\obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\node_modules\core-js\library\fn\string\bold.js'

I tried a suggestion I found online to change the settings by going to e terminal window and running the following command:

sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 200000

but that did not change anything, still the same errors when i run the project.  The odd thin is that I actually have two projects in the solution and the 2nd one actually runs, but it is a much smaller project and only a console app that dows not start up a web server, etc.

I am assuming that the upgrade to 10.15.7 had something to do with this but no cluee where to go now.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'll be darned... it was a code change.  I copied the project over to a PC and ran and got the same result.  Went through last changes one by one undoing them and found that one of my controllers had an issue that for some reason prevented it from running.  How to determine that from the log is another question but at least that answers that.  Evidently all the "too many open files" messages in debug log are not an issue, which also seems odd.